# How to calculate from date to date, MySQL?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, date

Is there a query that can use to sum up data from date until another date? If not, can you guys can share an idea how to do it in VB.NET.

Comment: I have a table that contain 3 field ( Num (PRIMARY), Total , Date ). Now, I want to calculate that 'Total' field from a date until another date.

Answer (score 3):

`SELECT sum(your_column1), sum(your_column2) ... FROM your_table WHERE your_date_field BETWEEN "from date comes here" AND "to date comes here"`

Comment: It’s important to note that the BETWEEN operator is inclusive on the boundaries, so that, for example “BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-02-01' comprises 32 days.”

Comment: That looks great but I only have one field for the total, how to sum it from row to row?

Comment: You mean: `SELECT sum(Total) FROM your_table WHERE your_date_field BETWEEN "from date comes here" AND "to date comes here"` ?

Comment: It didn't work. I think there is something wrong with WHERE your_date_field BETWEEN "from date comes here" AND "to date comes here". The result is nothing.